# reCaptcha script blocks my AJAX form from sending the e-mail

Tags: php, recaptcha-v3

I have created a Contact form that is sending my contact form data using AJAX.

```html
<form action="inc/contact.php" method="POST" id="contact-form">
  <div class="messages"></div>
  <div class="row controls">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group-meta form-group mb-30">
        <label for="name">Name*</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" name="name" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group-meta form-group mb-30">
        <label for="email">Email*</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="john.doe@mybusiness.com" name="email" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="input-group-meta form-group mb-30">
        <label for="message">Message*</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Your message*" name="message" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12"><button class="button-class form-button g-recaptcha" type="submit" name="submit" value="send" data-sitekey="6Lc8GI4iAAAAAFxgjs6MQwHdtp5ZjLcgIDQKsJSL" data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='submit'>Send Message</button></div>
    <div class="success-message">Thanks for Contacting Us!</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is the validation script

```html
<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    validateMe();

  })

  function validateMe() {
    //  console.log('validate me');
    $('label').css('color', 'white');

    var error = []; //this array holds the error messages
    var emailReg = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/; //regex for email validation
    //console.log($('#contact-form input'));
    $('#contact-form input').each(function() { //goes through all input fields
      var inputName = $(this).attr('name'); //assigns to inputName the name of each field
      if ($(this).val().length > 4) {
        //  console.log($(this).attr('name'));

        if (inputName == 'email' && !emailReg.test($(this).val())) //if it is not a valid email
        {
          error.push($(this).attr('name'));
          console.log('invalid email');
        }

      } else {
        error.push($(this).attr('name')); //we are pushing the error messages into this array
      }
    })


    //one more time for the text textarea

    $('#contact-form textarea').each(function() { //goes through all input fields
      var inputTextname = $(this).attr('name'); //assigns to inputName the name of each field
      if ($(this).val().length < 4) {
        //  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
        error.push($(this).attr('name'));
      }

    })


    if (error.length == 0) {
      $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
        console.log('submitted');
        $('.success-message').show(1000);

        function onSubmit(token) {
          document.getElementById("form-button").submit();
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "inc/contact.php",
          data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
          }
        })

        e.preventDefault();
      });
    } else {
      for (x = 0; x < error.length; x++) { //loops through all the different errors
        $('label[for="' + error[x] + '"]').css('color', 'red');
        console.log(error[x]);
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

Everything works fine up to here. When i try to add the reCaptcha v3. Script the contact form stops to send and i get the error.
I have tried to move the reCaptcha script onSubmit function to the Footer but still the same.

```html
ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onSubmit
```

Comment: Why have you put the `function onSubmit(token) {
          document.getElementById("form-button").submit();
        }` inside another function, and then inside an `if` block? That means it'll only be declared in certain circumstances, and only be accessible by other code within that function. Generally, declaring functions inside other functions is not necessary, and creates more problems than it solves (unless you have a specific reason for doing so, but if you did, you'd probably know the reason and understand more about what the effect would be. Somehow I doubt that's the case here.)

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to have two different snippets of code handling the submit scenario, anyway. Your code needs a bit more thought.

Comment: `document.getElementById("form-button").submit()` - you can not "submit" a button. _Forms_ can be submitted, _buttons_ can be clicked.